# run npm pack using child_process.exec

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, exec, child-process

I'm facing some weird behavior when runing `npm pack` using the `child_process.exec` method.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

function execCommand( command ) {
  exec(
    command,
    ( err, stdout, stderr ) => {
      if ( err != null ) {
        throw err;
      }
      console.log( 'stdout -> ', stdout );
      console.log( 'stderr -> ', stderr );
    }
  );
}

function packProject( projectName ) {
  console.log('Packing Project');
  const distDir = `dist/${projectName}`;
  execCommand('cd "'+distDir+'" && npm pack', {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  });
}

packProject('test-app')
```

It does execute both commands as expected, but then it doesn't terminate the process after running npm pack.

```
Packing Project
stdout ->
stderr ->
stdout ->
stderr ->
stdout ->
stderr ->
```

I'm not getting any errors nor warnings during the process. Only after pressing Ctrl+C. But I suppose it's only because the process was manually terminated.

```
^Cnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225786
```